# How I can add tooltip text for SKU product form in magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento2

Can anybody please tell me how I can add tooltip text for SKU in magento 2.2.5 admin panel product add/edit form.

Comment: Hey can you share your exact requirement as we are not able to understand what exactly your requirement is thanks.

Comment: My requirement is adding tooltip text for sku  in product add/edit form in magento admin panel.

Comment: so for adding tool tip text you can create  product attribute and can assign value in it. once you created and assign text then you can easily fetch it on product page.

Comment: for already added attributes like sku what has to do?

Comment: Once you have created the attribute and assigned value to it you should run indexing so that newly created attribute will be save in backend.
For showing this value on frontend you need to get it's value on product detail page once you have its value you can populate it on sku Div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using modifiers in magento 2

```
  $skuPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath('sku', $meta, null, 'children');

    if ($skuPath) {
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $skuPath . static::META_CONFIG_PATH,
            $meta,
            [               
                    'dataScope' =>  'sku',  
                      'tooltip' =>['description'=>'Sku tooltip text'],


            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but didnt work for me .See my question 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321496/add-tooltip-with-custom-product-attribute-in-magento2